# Erro de compilação do VBScript ao executar ficheiro bat para envio de email

Tags: script

O erro está descrito na imagem. Alguém me sabe dizer o motivo? Já tentei guardar o ficheiro com `encoded` `ANSI`  mas continua a não dar.

```
 Set objMail = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
    Set objConf = CreateObject("CDO.Configuration")
    Set objFlds = objConf.Fields
    objFlds.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2 'cdoSendUsingPort
    objFlds.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "smtp.your-site-url.com" 'your smtp server domain or IP address goes here
    objFlds.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25 'default port for email
    'uncomment next three lines if you need to use SMTP Authorization
    'objFlds.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = "your-username"
    'objFlds.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = "your-password"
    'objFlds.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1 'cdoBasic
    objFlds.Update
    objMail.Configuration = objConf
    objMail.FromName = "Your Name"
    objMail.From = "your@address.com"
    objMail.To = "destination@address.com"
    objMail.Subject = "Email Subject Text"
    objMail.TextBody = "The message of the email..."
    objMail.Send
    Set objFlds = Nothing
    Set objConf = Nothing
    Set objMail = Nothing
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: qual editor estás usando?

Comment: Já está resolvido.
Basta remover a linha 12 que não será necessária uma vez que a caixa ja esta configurada para o Nome correto.

Comment: Você pode postar uma resposta explicando como foi resolvido ou simplesmente editar sua pergunta para que os outros usuários entendam.

Comment: Já esta, agora pode votar para que demonstre a resolução pf

Answer (score 1):

Solução:

```
Set objMail = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
    Set objConf = CreateObject("CDO.Configuration")
    Set objFlds = objConf.Fields
    objFlds.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2 'cdoSendUsingPort
    objFlds.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "smtp.your-site-url.com" 'your smtp server domain or IP address goes here
    objFlds.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25 'default port for email
    'uncomment next three lines if you need to use SMTP Authorization
    'objFlds.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = "your-username"
    'objFlds.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = "your-password"
    'objFlds.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1 'cdoBasic
    objFlds.Update
    objMail.Configuration = objConf
    objMail.From = "your@address.com"
    objMail.To = "destination@address.com"
    objMail.Subject = "Email Subject Text"
    objMail.TextBody = "The message of the email..."
    objMail.Send
    Set objFlds = Nothing
    Set objConf = Nothing
    Set objMail = Nothing
```

Guardar o ficheiro com o `encoding` `ANSI` e extensão `.vbs` e já ira funcionar perfeitamente. Para alem disso teremos de dar permissão na caixa de correio para enviar email por smtp.